# Run Python os.system from a sub package

Tags: python, macos

I need to run a python file using an older python 2.6 version installed with an external software.
To do this I have resorted to using `os.system` such as

```
os.system('""path/old_python.exe" "file.py""')
```

*(note that the odd no. of ('") is due to the path containing a space  `c:/program files (x86)/..`  as I am running on windows.)*

This code string works well if run from a root directory. However, I would like to place this os.system call in a module within a sub-package to my root and thereafter run it from a root module. So the hierarchy would look like this:

```
/root
    call_os_module.py
    /subpack1
        os_module.py
        file.py
```

If I run this I receive the error:

```
path/old_python.exe: can't open file 'file.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have added the full path to `subpack1` to `sys.path`. However, I still receive the same error and os can't find the file. How do I solve this?

Comment: Why can't you just use `os.system('""path/old_python.exe" "subpack1/file.py""')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these questions:

- [How in Python to run external Python script with the current Python interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243474/how-in-python-to-run-external-python-script-with-current-python-interpreter/21244064#21244064)
- [Relative paths in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python)
- in general: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+relative+path